# Update not working in MySql procedure through JDBC call

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a MySql procedure which contains two update queries for two tables.
The proc works fine when I call it in MySql Workbench. But when I call it through my java code, only one update statement works.

I changed the order in which the two update statements are called but every time, it's the same query that doesn't update. The proc is

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `theProc`(
IN ADMIN_EMAIL_ID_1 varchar(200), 
IN IS_EMAIL_ID_1 varchar(100),
IN IS_EMAIL_ID_2 varchar(100),
IN Build_floor varchar(100) ,
IN Locayshan  varchar(200),
IN referenceid varchar(100))
BEGIN

UPDATE mySchema.table1 SUMM 
   SET SUMM.PHY_MAIL_IDS =ADMIN_EMAIL_ID_1, SUMM.swon_flag = Build_floor, SUMM.IS_MAIL_IDS = IS_EMAIL_ID_1,  SUMM.IS_MAIL_IDS2 = IS_EMAIL_ID_2
       WHERE SUMM.REF_ID=referenceid;/*Works fine*/


UPDATE mySchema.table2 MAS
    SET MAS.Location=Locayshan where MAS.REF_ID=referenceid; /*This doesn't work*/

END
```

And my java code is

```
String query = "{call mySchema.theProc(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
                cstmt = c.prepareCall(query);
                cstmt.setString(1, "a.b@c.com$$f.g@c.com");     
                cstmt.setString(2, "d.e@c.com");
                cstmt.setString(3, "");
                cstmt.setString(4, "2nd Floor North Wing$$4th Floor South Wing");
                cstmt.setString(5, "California$$Moscow$$");
                cstmt.setString(6, "666");
cstmt.executeUpdate();
```

The string "California$$Moscow$$" is supposed to be stored in table2 but it isn't.

Is there a different way in which I should call the proc? Please help.

Comment: what mysql logs say?

Comment: How do you prepare the `CallableStatement`? The code shown never does that. Also do you get any exceptions?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks. I missed that. I've edited the question now